# ng-include two controllers from two different apps

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two apps (app1 and app2) and somewhere inside of them two index.html files (one each).
These files have a

`<div> ng-include="header.html".</div>`

The header.html file has a button with an `ng-if="showButton()"`.

The function `showButton()` is in `app1.controller1`. So, since now was ok because that controller used to set that boolean value (`showButton()` result) correclty.
The problem comes when `app2` through his `controller2` tries to set that value aswell.

Basically, can (and if yes how) two controller of two different apps point to the same variable in an html file?

```
showButton() in app1.controller1
showButton() in app2.controller2
```

and those functions are binded to the same value in the `header.html` file.
I read about directives that can be related to multiple controllers but examples were single-app based.

The thing that truly confuse me is that `ng-include="header.html"` with that `"header.html"` having a value to be accessed from two different apps

The only thing that is close to a solution at the moment is a brutal copy-paste of code and i wanted to know if there was a smarter way to do it.

Thank you.